# How to compare data of 2 tables?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I will compare 2 tables data in same database. For example:

```
Table 1:
--------
Order number, user_id etc

Table 2:
--------
Order number
```

=> One user can make more then one order. So I need to check all the order of an user  with table 2 order numbers. If found then it will be print true otherwise false. I was trying the following code:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$user_id= $user->get('id');

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT virtuemart_user_id, order_number, order_total, created_on FROM `#__virtuemart_orders` WHERE `virtuemart_user_id`='$user_id' AND `order_status`='C'");
$row = $db->loadRowList();

foreach($row as $d){

// I NEED TO COMPARE THE LOGIC HERE WITH THE SECOND TABLE. If it found match 
// with table 2 then another column will be created & print out that 
// "We found your order"

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=orders&layout=details&order_number=".$d['1'] ."'target='_blank'>".$d['1']."</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=orders&layout=details&order_number=".$d['1'] ."'target='_blank'>".$d['2']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=orders&layout=details&order_number=".$d['1'] ."'target='_blank'>".$d['3']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql to do this in your query:

Something like

```
SELECT virtuemart_user_id, user_name, COUNT(virtuemart_order_id) AS num_orders
FROM virtuemart_users
LEFT JOIN virtuemart_orders USING (virtuemart_user_id)
WHERE `virtuemart_user_id`='$user_id' AND `order_status`='C'
```

will give a table with each user's id, name and number of completed orders (actually, the number of rows we managed to match).

You can go from the virtuemart_orders table to another table using the same logic, and you can use a `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` if you only want rows where both tables have the shared id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But main problem is in table 2 there is no primary key. The order number is in FileValue field. I tried this code in foreach function <pre>$file_query= $db->setQuery("SELECT `FieldValue` FROM `#__rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldValue`='$d[1]' ");
$results = $file_query->loadObjectList();</pre>. But I can't make compare with each order. I mean if it's match with order number 5 from table 1 with same order number in Table 2 then it will print successful message beside the order number.

Comment: OK I got the solution.